# Android, ListView, слушатели

Tags: android-sdk, android

Помогите! В `ListView` я использую два слушателя: `OnItemClickListener` и `OnItemLongCkickListener`. При долгом нажатии вызывается метод `onItemLongCkickListener`, а за ним `оnItemCkickListener`. Как сделать, чтобы после вызова `оnItemLongCkickListener`, не вызывался `оnItemCkickListener`. Или как сделать, чтобы при долгом удержании, всплывало меню, как `onContextItemSelected` для `View`, но при этом я получал позицию нажатого элемента в меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick%28android.view.View%29) и этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5428268/3212712):

Вам надо из `onItemLongCkickListener` возвращать **true**, чтобы предотвратить вызов других обработчиков нажатий.

Код должен выглядеть так:

```
listvideos.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) 
    {
         //какой-то код, что-то делающий
         return true;   
    }
});
```

Comment: Не выходит. Когда я пытаюсь дописать ``public boolean onItemLongClickListener``, пишет что метод не может быть таким. P.S. Просто вернуть **true** не выходит. 

Вы еще написали про метод ``onLongClick``, но он не подходит. Мне нужна позиция нажатого элемента списка.

Comment: Покажите ваш код в вопросе.

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: Ух ты! Заработало. Но теперь вопрос: почему? Как это работает? Дайте ответ, если не сложно. :D

Comment: Похоже с `OnItemClickListener` такая штука не прокатывает. Вот такой код не хочет работать.. Ну и ладно! :)

Comment: А хрен его знает, почему оно так))) Я вообще не пользую такой подход, а вешаю слушателей нажатий в адаптере в методе `getView()`

Comment: Для меня такой подход еще не понятен.. :)

Comment: Без него никак. Изучите вопрос и можно будет не мучиться с этими непонятными слушателями списка)